# How to add additional firebase modules to a Swift project?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I am doing a project on swift and I used cocoapods but only installed the core and auth modules for firebase. I need the database module as well, but it appears as though I will have to make a new plist and make a new .xcworkspace file too. Won't this delete all the code I have? I don't understand how to add additional modules, and would appreciate any and all help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just edit your `Podfile`, add `pod 'Firebase/Database'` to it and re-run `pod install`. This will update the existing `.xcworkspace`, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect.